# Cant find variable not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to get the total value from the dealers hand and players hand, however I cant seem to get it as the variable is not defined. I simply want to compare the scores so I tell if they both hit blackjack, who lost or who won

Thank you.

```
import playing_cards
import random
players_hand = []
dealers_hand = []

#Gives point values to the cards
def get_hand_total(hand):
    pointCount = 0
    for i in range(0, len(hand)):
        if ("K" in hand[i] or "Q" in hand[i]  or "J" in hand[i]  or "T" in hand[i]):
            pointCount += 10

#As aces can be 1 or 11, if the current pointCount + 11 is more than 21, it will add 1.
        elif("A" in hand[i]): 
            if (pointCount + 11) > 21:
                pointCount  += 1

            else:
                pointCount  += 11      

        else:
                for num in range(1,10):
                    if str(num) in hand[i]:
                        pointCount  += num
    if len(hand) > 1:
        if (("T" in hand[0]  or "K" in hand[0-1] or "Q" in hand[0-1]  or "J" in hand[0-1]  or "T" in hand[0-1])):
            pointCount  = 21


    return(pointCount)




#Figures out what suites the cards belong too
def display_hand(hand_text, hand):
    character = ""
    character  = character.join(hand)
    str_conc = ""
    for i in range(1, len(character ), 2):
        if("S" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of of Spades \ "

        elif("H" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Hearts \ "

        elif("C" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Clubs \ "

        elif("D" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Diamonds \ "
    str_conc = str_conc[:-2]
    print(hand_text,str(get_hand_total(hand)) + ":", str_conc)




#Dealers Cards
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
display_hand("Dealer\'s hand is", dealers_hand)



#Players Hand
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
players_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
players_hand.append(card)
display_hand("Player\'s hand is", players_hand)



#Who wins?
if dealers_hand == 21:
    print('dealer wins')
```

Here is the playing_cards file as well:;

```
#
# playing_cards module - PSP Assignment 1, sp2, 2017.
# DO NOT MODIFY!
#

import random


# Deck of cards - first letter represents the face value and
# second letter represents the suit
deck = ['AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
        'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
        'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS',
        'AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC']

# Playing deck in use
playing_deck = []


# Function to determine whether there are any cards left in the
# deck of playing cards
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: True if the deck is empty, False otherwise
def is_empty_deck():

    # Check to see whether playing deck is empty
    return len(playing_deck) == 0


# Function to rebuild and shuffle the deck
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: Nothing is returned from the function.
def reset_deck():
    global playing_deck

    # Create new playing deck
    playing_deck = deck.copy()

    # Shuffle deck
    random.shuffle(playing_deck)


# Function to deal one card
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: A string (containing two characters) representing
# the card delt, i.e. '2H' meaning 2 of Hearts
def deal_one_card():

    # Check to see whether there are any cards left
    if is_empty_deck():

        # Rebuild and shuffle deck
        reset_deck()

    # Return a card (string of two characters)
    return playing_deck.pop(0)
```

Comment: Hard to tell anything without the source of your module "playing_cards". When I run the program it obviously tells me that it cannot found the module "playing_cards", which is used in the program.

Comment: added the playing_cards.py file, should be good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below update to the main file. You have a method in place to check the result of the hands. So running that method and then checking the sums against each other to determine a winner would work.

You have tried to check dealers_hand == 21 however it is a list and the list does not contain the scores for the hand. You need to pass the hand through get_hand_score(hand) to determine the results. When you have the results you can calculate and determine a winner. :)

```
import playing_cards
import random
players_hand = []
dealers_hand = []

#Gives point values to the cards
def get_hand_total(hand):
    pointCount = 0
    for i in range(0, len(hand)):
        if ("K" in hand[i] or "Q" in hand[i]  or "J" in hand[i]  or "T" in hand[i]):
            pointCount += 10

#As aces can be 1 or 11, if the current pointCount + 11 is more than 21, it will add 1.
        elif("A" in hand[i]): 
            if (pointCount + 11) > 21:
                pointCount  += 1

            else:
                pointCount  += 11      

        else:
                for num in range(1,10):
                    if str(num) in hand[i]:
                        pointCount  += num
    if len(hand) > 1:
        if (("T" in hand[0]  or "K" in hand[0-1] or "Q" in hand[0-1]  or "J" in hand[0-1]  or "T" in hand[0-1])):
            pointCount  = 21


    return(pointCount)




#Figures out what suites the cards belong too
def display_hand(hand_text, hand):
    character = ""
    character  = character.join(hand)
    str_conc = ""
    for i in range(1, len(character ), 2):
        if("S" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of of Spades \ "

        elif("H" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Hearts \ "

        elif("C" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Clubs \ "

        elif("D" in character [i]):
            str_conc = str_conc + str(character [i - 1]) + " of Diamonds \ "
    str_conc = str_conc[:-2]
    print(hand_text,str(get_hand_total(hand)) + ":", str_conc)

def winner(d, p):
    dealerTotal = get_hand_total(d)
    playerTotal = get_hand_total(p)

    if dealerTotal > playerTotal and dealerTotal <= 21:
        print("Dealer Wins!")
    elif dealerTotal == playerTotal:
        print("Draw!")
    elif playerTotal <= 21:
        print("Player Wins!")



#Dealers Cards
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
display_hand("Dealer\'s hand is", dealers_hand)



#Players Hand
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
players_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
players_hand.append(card)
display_hand("Player\'s hand is", players_hand)

# Who wins?
winner(dealers_hand, players_hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share the complete code, without it won't be able to help you, but I would like to point out that you declare 'dealers_hand' as a list so you can't compare it like "dealers_hand==21". You will have to loop through the elements of the list and then sum it and then compart the sum.